# Первый запуск symphony framework

Tags: php, nginx, symfony3

В данный момент есть сервер Nginx + php 5.6
Есть поддомен под него записана папка на сервере - parser_dev в которой запускается index.php
Все что пишется в index.php - изменяется на начальной странице
затем я вошел в консоль - установил simphony
создал новый проект

```
micle@parser:/var/www/parser_dev$ symfony new  parser
```

Протестировал

```
micle@parser:/var/www/parser_dev$ php parser/bin/symfony_requirements

Symfony Requirements Checker
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

> PHP is using the following php.ini file:
  /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

> Checking Symfony requirements:
  ...................W................W........


 [OK]
 Your system is ready to run Symfony projects
```

Затем в index.php написал

```
<?php    
     require_once __DIR__ .'/parser/app/autoload.php';
```

Обновил страницу - показывает белый экран.
Разработчики говорят что начальная страница должна быть с приветствием пользователя по умолчанию. Что еще необходимо сделать что бы уже можно было приступать к работе?
Запускать команду

```
php bin/console server:run
```

админ не рекомендует - он говорит что уже сервер настроен и запуск внутреннего php сервера приведет к необратимым последствиям

Comment: Если вы действительно хотите использовать symfony с nginx, вам нужно правильно его сконфигурировать. Вот пример корректного конфига: http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx Никакие `index.php` вам не нужны.

Comment: Спасибо @Dmitriy Simushev - предал информацию сис админу - все настроил и заработало - теперь пришло время познакомиться мне с первым для себя фреймворком (уже прочел про шаблоны проектирования, отлавливания ошибок, тестирование)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы действительно хотите использовать symfony с nginx, вам нужно правильно его сконфигурировать. Вот пример корректного конфига для symfony + nginx + php-fpm:

```
server {
    server_name domain.tld www.domain.tld;
    root /var/www/project/web;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }
    # DEV
    # This rule should only be placed on your development environment
    # In production, don't include this and don't deploy app_dev.php
    # or config.php
    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }
    # PROD
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

Конфиг выше взят из [официальной документации symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx).